# getUTCMonth() and getUTCDate draws an error when comparing certain dates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, utc

I have tried to create a method to format some dates in my datatable which are based on the results from a sql server of ours. I cannot see any reason why certain dates would draw an error and the errors seem to be from my if statements. For instance when checking the month and day of Thu Dec 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) in my If statement it draws an error from what I can see. I have included my function below:

```
          dateFormat(date1, date2) {
                startDate = new Date(date1)
                endDate = new Date(date2)

                let TotalDays = Math.ceil((endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                console.log('start')
                console.log(startDate)
                console.log(startDate.getUTCDate())
                console.log(startDate.getUTCMonth())
                console.log(endDate)
                console.log(endDate.getUTCDate())
                console.log(endDate.getUTCMonth())
                if (TotalDays == 364 || TotalDays == 365 || TotalDays == 366) {
                    if (startDate.getUTCMonth() == 0 && StartDate.getUTCDate() == 1) {
                        //this is January start date
                        console.log('complete')
                        return 'CY' + dayjs(endDate).format('YYYY')
                    } else if (startDate.getUTCMonth() == 6 && startDate.getUTCDate() == 1) {
                        //this is July start date
                        console.log('complete')
                        return 'FY' + dayjs(endDate).format('YYYY')
                    } else {
                        //not a true FY or CY so default to RY
                        console.log('complete')
                        return 'RY' + dayjs(endDate).format('YYYY')
                    }
                } else {
                    //this date is not on a full calendar year or fiscal year
                    console.log('complete')
                    return dayjs(startDate).format('MMM YYYY') + ' - ' + dayjs(endDate).format('MMM YYYY')
                }

            },
```

and my console log draws an error inside of one of my axios requests hence the promise error. However, I used console.log to see where the code is breaking as it loops through my data.

```
                axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: window.location.origin + '/api/list',
                data: [],
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                }
            }).then(response => {

                this.Results = response.data.map((obj) => {
                    return { ...obj, formattedPeriodBegins: this.dateFormat(obj.date_begins, obj.date_ends) };
                })

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error.response.data.error);
            });
```

My console log shows the following output. Which traces my code to failing at the if statement before the next complete tag I use to output.

```
(index):5186 Mon Apr 01 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):5187 1
(index):5188 3
(index):5189 Tue Jun 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):5190 30
(index):5191 5
(index):5208 complete
(index):5185 start
(index):5186 Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
(index):5187 1
(index):5188 0
(index):5189 Thu Dec 31 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
(index):5190 31
(index):5191 11
(index):5272 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at (index):5272:48
```

Comment: `console.log(error.response.data.error);`  try changing to `console.log(error)`,

Comment: Wow you sir saved me. I did not realize changing to error would allow me to see the error. The issue was my variable had a uppercase letter rather than startDate in the second inequality. Thanks so much! If you want to write that error then I will select your answer

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately your error handler caused an error :).  Easy done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely because your not seeing the real reason for the error.

This is because

```
}).catch(error => {                
  console.log(error.response.data.error);
});
```

`error` is likely of type `Error`, the Error object will not have a `response` property, and then doing `error.response.data` will be reading undefined.

The fix here, is just log the `error` object in full.

```
}).catch(error => {                
  console.log(error);
});
```

A slight note, generally speaking `catch (e) { console.log(e); }` is something you shouldn't be doing very often, as errors propagating is usually what you want.  So just removing the `.catch(e) {`  might even be better..

Answer (score 1):

The error seems not related to Date or dayjs, it's rather because of either response or err.response is undefined (likely a network error, should show in console).

Comment: Not a network error. Data is loaded and the map function is looping through array using my dateFormat function. The error is drawn inside that date function. If i remove the if statement checking getUTCMonth and getUTCDate then it completes the map() function, So it has to do with those inequalities. Strange to see it loops through some dates though but gets held up at that one that says GMT -500

Comment: The error you've shown in screenshot is because of the reason I mentioned. Maybe the error was thrown from then() block, so err.response doesn't have a value in catch block.